# How do I convert '2020-06-15' to '2020-06' in postgreSQL (BigQuery example provided)?

Tags: postgresql

**Desired output:** change the date 2020-06-15 to a string that reads 2020-06

In BigQuery StandardSQL the following works

```
SELECT
CONCAT( 
      CAST( EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) ) AS STRING, '-', CAST( EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) AS STRING)
      ) as year_date
FROM 
table
```

This gives you '20202-06' in BigQuery. 
In PostgreSQL I get the following error

*ERROR:  function concat(character varying, "unknown", character varying) does not exist*

I've tried all sorts with this and still can't get the right answer. 
e.g.

```
concat(extract(year from date)::text, '-', extract(month from date)::text ) as year_date
concat(cast(extract(year from date) as varchar(16)), '-', cast(extract(month from date) as varchar(16)) ) as year_date,
```

However, I still end up with the same error?

Many thanks

Comment: `concat` in Postgres is `||`. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL

Comment: It is also concat: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_char`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) to format a dates, timestamps, and numbers.

```
# select to_char('2020-06-15'::date, 'YYYY-MM');
 to_char 
---------
 2020-06
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT
CONCAT( 
      CAST( EXTRACT(YEAR FROM current_date)  AS varchar), '-', CAST( EXTRACT(MONTH FROM current_date) AS varchar)
      ) as year_date;
 year_date 
-----------
 2020-6
```